# trying to scrape url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

So im trying to get all the url from the free games site on steam however it keeps returning empty. I dont know what I'm doing wrong here, image below shows the path

```
result = requests.get("https://steamdb.info/upcoming/free/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

urls = []
for td_tag in soup.find_all('td'):
    a_tag = td_tag.find('a')
    urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])

print(urls)
```

[image]

Comment: it can check some headers - usually "User Agent". It can use JavaScript to add it - requests/BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript. At first display `result.content` to see what you get - maybe there is message for bots/script. You can also turn off JavaScript in browser and reload URL in browser to see what you can get.

Comment: Is there any better way to scrape the URL other than Beautiful soup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use header `User-Agent` and it can't be short `Mozilla/5.0` but full string from real web browser

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
}

result = requests.get("https://steamdb.info/upcoming/free/", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

#print(result.content)
urls = []
for td_tag in soup.find_all('td'):
    a_tag = td_tag.find('a')
    if a_tag:
        urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])

print(urls)
```

Comment: is there any specific way to only get the data from the div <div class="pre-table-title" id="live-promotions"> ?

Comment: ie. use `find('div', {'id': 'live-promotions"}).find_all('a')` ?

Comment: BTW: you can also use CSS selections `soup.select('div#live-promotions a')` . If you use `lxml` instead of `Beautifulsoup` then you can use xpath like `soup.xpath('//div[@id="live-promotions"]//a'):`

Comment: that only returns <a href="#live-promotions">Currently live promotions</a>

Comment: Its because the live promotions is separate from the game URLs, I had to use  urls = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table-products table-responsive-flex table-hover text-left table-sortable'}).find_all("a"). Thanks very much